# How to run something in Git Bash from Windows command

Tags: windows, cmd, git-bash

I use this Windows command to open Git Bash:

```
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login 
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

I want to run a script from Git Bash now.
How can I do to run a script from Windows command on Git Bash?

I want that Git Bash run `git ex` (a script from me) when it is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `bash` or `sh` to run a bash script from DOS.

Simply write your bash script in a file called `git-xxx` (replace `xxx` by something more expressive) (no extension).

Then, from your DOS (provided your `%PATH%` include `<git>/bin`), call:

```
git xxx
```

That will launch the `git-xxx` script (it needs to be somewhere in your PATH too), through the git `bash.exe` session.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is this still a feature in recent versions of git?

Comment: @jkokorian No, it is a known feature for quite some time now. But your git-xxx needs to be in your %PATH%.